# Calculating the sum and average of a random array

Tags: java, arrays, sum, mean

I am trying to create 3 methods which calculate the sum and average of a random array then outputting the result.

I am trying to get an output similar to -
java RandomArray 5
9 7 2 1 4
Sum: 23
Mean: 4.6

but I am getting "Usage: java RandomArray . Example: java RandomArray 5"

if you can spot the errors in my code and help with how to get this output.

```
public class RandomArray {

private int[] numbers; //instance variable

/**
 *  Constructor
 *
 *@param  size  The size of the array
 */
public RandomArray(int size){
    numbers = new int[size];
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
        numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10); // a random number between 0-9
    }
}

/**
 *  a method to print the array elements
 */

public void printArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}       

/**
 *  A method to calculate the sum of all elements
 *
 *@return    The sum
 */
public int calSum(){
 int sum = 0;
 for (int value : numbers) {
     sum += value;
}
    return sum;

}

/**
 *  A method to calculate the mean of all elements
 *
 *@return    The mean
 */

public double calMean() {
    int sum = calSum();
    int length = numbers.length;

    return (double) sum / length;
}


/**
 *  a method to print the array elements in reverse order
 */
public void printReverse(){


}

/**
 *  A main method to test
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Check to see if the user has actually sent a paramter to the method
    if (args.length != 1){
        System.out.println("Usage: java RandomArray <NUM>. Example: java RandomArray 5");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // Create an instance of the class 
    RandomArray test = new RandomArray(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));


    // Print the array
    test.printArray();

    // Calculate the sum of all the values in the array and print it
    System.out.println("Sum: "+ test.calSum());

    // Calculate the mean of all the values in the array and print it
    System.out.println("Mean: "+ test.calMean());

    System.out.print("Reverse: ");
    test.printReverse();
}
```

}

Comment: *but what is confusing me is how to use it when using a random array* - Does it differ from a non-random array?

Comment: I notice a comment in your code "*Unsure which elements go here*" is this your actual question?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(numbers).summaryStatistics()` will give you an [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) on which you can call `getSum()` and `getAverage()`.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your method "printArray(int sum)" has the mistake. When you call the method you take a parameter sum, which is not needed. Then you try to create a second local variable with the name sum. This is impossible, because you already have a parameter called sum.

In your for loop you init antoher local variable called sum. You need a different name for that variable, since you only need it for counting the loop.

So remove your parameter sum and rename the variable used in the for loop.

This should work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayCalculations
{
    private int[] numbers;

    public ArrayCalculations(int size)
    {
        this.numbers = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            numbers[i] = randomNumber;
        }
    }

    public int calculateSum()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sum += numbers[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public float calculateAverage()
    {
        float sum = (float) calculateSum();

        return sum / numbers.length;
    }

    public void printArray()
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayCalculations ac = new ArrayCalculations(5); // initiates an array with 5 elements
        ac.printArray(); // prints the array to console
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + ac.calculateSum()); // prints the sum
        System.out.println("The average is: " + ac.calculateAverage()); // prints the average
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also explain to the OP what you have changed, why and what difference it makes :) This will make your answer a lot better

Comment: This is a pretty unusasble API. Separate the creation of the array from the calculation of averages. Make it reusable. Give the statistics calculation a nicely named static factory method `ArrayCalculations.statistics(int[] input)`. Finally - add some documentation!

Comment: Indeed, that was lazy. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s look at your sum method first:

```java
public int calSum(int sum) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int value : numbers) {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

- Why does this method accept a parameter? You just redeclare it on the next line anyway.
- Looks good otherwise.

Here’s a cleaned up version:

```java
public int calSum() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int value : numbers) {
        sum += value;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

---

Next up, mean average:

```java
public double calMean(int[] array){

    //Unsure which elements go here
}
```

- Again, why the parameter?
- Recall how we calculate the mean average: sum all elements, then divide by the number of elements.
- We’ve already got a method for calculating the sum, so we can use that.

```java
public double calMean() {
    int sum = calSum();
    int length = numbers.length;

    return (double) sum / length;
}
```

Note the use of `(double)` here. Without it, `cal / length` would be *integer division*, and the result would be rounded to the nearest whole number.